# "Run-Time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method." Range.values = Range.values

Tags: vba, excel, range

I am trying to copy a range of data from a Excel workbook to another workbook without the need of selecting any workbook during this process and using worksheet object names.

I want to do this because the selection process:

> Windows("SourceWorksheet").Activate - Sheet("SourceSheet").Select -
>   Range("SourceRange").Copy  -  Windows("DestinationWorksheet").Activate
>   - Sheet("DestinationSheet").Select - Range("DestinationRange").Paste

is very slow compare with

> DestinationWorkBook.DestinationSheet.Range("DestinationRange").Value =
>   SourceWorkBook.SourceWorkSheet.Range("SourceRange").Value

I have got this working using sheets tap names and letter ranges:

```
Workbooks(DestinationWorkBook).Sheets("DestinationSheet").Range("A:C").Value = _
       Workbooks(SoureceWorkBook).Sheets("SourceSheet").Range("A:C").Value
```

And also using semi-dynamic ranges and sheets tap names:

```
lastRow = Cells(Workbooks(Limits_Name).Sheets("SourceSheet").Rows.Count, _
          "A").End(xlUp).Row
Workbooks(DestinationWorkBook).Sheets("DestinationSheet").Range("A1:C" & lastRow).Value = _
          Workbooks(SourceWorkBook).Sheets("SourceSheet").Range("A1:C" & lastRow).Value
```

My problems starts when I use sheets object names instead of sheets names or cells instead of ranges. In those situation is when I get that error:

```
Workbooks(DestinationWorkBook).shtDestinationSheet.Range("A:C").Value = _
        Workbooks(SourceWorkBook).Sheets("SourceSheet").Range("A:C").Value 

OR

lastRow = Cells(Workbooks(SourceWorkBook).Sheets("SourceSheet").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
lastCol = Cells(1, Workbooks(SourceWorkBook).Sheets("SourceSheet").Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Workbooks(DestinationWorkBook).Sheets("DestinationSheet").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastRow, lastCol)).Value = _
   Workbooks(SourceWorkBook).Sheets("SourceSheet").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastRow, lastCol)).Value

OR (this is the ideal code)

lastRow = Cells(Workbooks(SourceWorkBook).Sheets("SourceSheet").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
lastCol = Cells(1, Workbooks(SourceWorkBook).Sheets("SourceSheet").Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Workbooks(DestinationWorkBook).shtDestinationSheet.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastRow, lastCol)).Value = _
   Workbooks(SourceWorkBook).Sheets("SourceSheet").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastRow, lastCol)).Value
```

I would like to know what is the difference between using Sheets("sheetname") and the and the sheet object name which can be given under the (name) property of the worksheet object properties.

If I use Sheets("SourceSheet").Range("") I do not need to select the sheet but using sthSourceSheet.Range("") I do.

I like to use sheet object names because the VBA code still works if the sheet name is modified.

Comment: maybe i got it wrong, but when setting a sheet-object the parent (workbook) is includet... having `workbook_object.sheet_object` normally leads to an error...

Comment: Thanks for the comment @DirkReichel, you are right, that solve part of the issue. Now this code is working: `shtDestinationSheet.Range("A:C").Value = Workbooks(SourceWorkBook).Sheets("SourceSheet").Range("A:C").Value`  and the semi dinamic range is also working: `shtDestinationSheet.Range("A1:C" & lastRow).Value = Workbooks(SoureceWorkBook).Sheets("SourceSheet").("A1:C" & lastRow).Value` .  But I cannot still use full dynamic ranges using cells(): `.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastRow, lastCol))`

Comment: normally there should be no problem... what error did you get? does this still happen if you use a string for `Range()` like `str = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastRow, lastCol)).Address` and then simply use `.Range(str)`?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reponse @DirkReichel , you solution works: `Str = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastRow, lastCol)).Address` and `shtDestinationSheet.Range(Str).Value = Workbooks(SourceWorkBook).Sheets("SourceSheet").Range(Str).Value`. But replacing Range(Str) with Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastRow, lastCol)) I got this error: Run-Time Error '1004' Application-defined or object-defined error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First problem (solved):
When using an object for a `Worksheet` this includes also the `Workbook`.
While the `Worksheet-Object` is not a child of the workbook itself inside of the syntax like `Workbook.Worksheet_Object`. So either use `Workbook.Worksheet(Worksheet_Object.Name)` or just `Worksheet_Object`

Second probem (solved):
There is a problem using `Range(Cells(), Cells())` in a non-active workbook... Using only `Cells()` with no parent sometimes causes trouble cus VBA want's to use a full path. Just `Cells` will retun a [workbook]Sheet!Range while using with a different parent this causes an error. VBA will get a return like: `Wb1.Ws1.Range(Wb2.Ws2.Range)`.

You can try something like:

```
htDestinationSheet.Range(htDestinationSheet.Cells(1, 1), htDestinationSheet.Cells(lastRow, lastCol)).Value = Workbooks(SourceWorkBook).Sheets("SourceSheet").Range(Workbooks(SourceWorkBook).Sheets("SourceSheet").Cells(1, 1), Workbooks(SourceWorkBook).Sheets("SourceSheet").Cells(lastRow, lastCol)).Value
```

which should work... However: i think it's better to stay with `str` (looks better)

Comment: Thanks @DirkReichel, that solution works perfectly and because of you explanation, now I know why it did not work previously. I totally agree with you `str` solution is much nicer. Thank you very much again!